# VBA Unique values in Combobox list from Listbox column / field

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, listbox, unique

I am looking to make a Combobox list only the unique values in a Listbox field / column every time the listbox's list changes.

For example column 3 in the listbox contains multiple instances of Apple, Strawberry and Banana. I want the combobox to contain only Apple, Strawberry and Banana once each.

Any elegant ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing duplicates from a list can be achieved using a dictionary. For the following code to work, you have to add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to your [references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference).

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        dict.Add Key:=ListBox1.List(i), Item:=0
    Next i
    ComboBox1.List = dict.Keys
End Sub
```

I haven't had the opportunity to test it, let me know if it works.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. I just changed ListBox1.List(i) to ListBox1.List(i,3) to only select one column to add.

Answer (score 1):

**Assign unique 3rd column items to Combobox**

- `[1]` There are several ways to receive *uniques* (dictionary, arraylist); I demonstrate an approach using `FilterXML()` function (available since vers. 2013+) as well as a tricky way to isolate the *3rd listbox column* by the listbox'es `.Column` property via `arr = Application.Index(Me.ListBox1.Column, 3, 0)`, thus receiving a "flat" array without loops,
- `[2]` create a simple wellformed *xml* structure based on the array data and provide for an *XPath* search string to get uniques and
- `[3]` assign the "vertical" 2-dim uniques received via `FilterXML()` to the combobox'es `.List` property. Furthermore I added a small error handler providing for the case of a single item.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    If Me.ListBox1.ListCount = 0 Then Exit Sub              ' Escape if no list items available
    With Application
        '[1] get 3rd column items of listbox
        Dim arr: arr = .Index(Me.ListBox1.Column, 3, 0)     ' Index uses 1-based indices

        '[2] create FilterXML arguments to get uniques
        Dim XContent As String: XContent = "<t><s>" & Join(arr, "</s><s>") & "</s></t>"
        Dim XP As String: XP = "//s[not(preceding::*=.)]"   ' XPath expression searching uniques
        '[3] assign "vertical" 2-dim uniques to combobox
        Dim uniques: uniques = .FilterXML(XContent, XP)     ' get uniques to combobox
        On Error Resume Next:  Me.ComboBox1.List = uniques  ' assign uniques to combobox
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Me.ComboBox1.AddItem uniques
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. This is a very well thought out solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try below codes and let us know your feedback.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            dict.Item(ListBox1.List(i)) = vbNullString
        Next i
    ComboBox1.List = dict.keys
    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I went with the first answer. This one was very similar. I appreciate your contribution.

Comment: No issue. Yes almost similar but great thing is no need to add any reference.